# Facebook HashTag Count and Topic Feed API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

Since the Facebook has introduce the hashtag, I've been interested to use that in my web application. Currently I am trying to get the hash tag counts from this api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/hashtag_counter/v2.1

But everytime I've tried to call the API it gives me "400 Bad Request". It throws the exception and this is the exception message.

"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",

I am also getting this same exception one with this api too.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/topic_feed/v2.1

Can please someone let me know what how can I solve this issue and get the count of hashtag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doc says
This API is restricted to partners in the Public Content Solutions program. So it's not available for public use